# How does "startTimestamp" option work for the rate-micro-batch format?

Tags: java, apache-spark

This is for Spark 3.5.0, haven't tried other versions.

I wrote a simple Spark streaming app, using the `rate-micro-batch` format, which is used for generating test data.

According to [this guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#creating-streaming-dataframes-and-streaming-datasets) it has an option `startTimestamp`, which is the starting value of generated time. But changing this option doesn't seem to do anything, I tried setting it to different values, and the starting time is always around `1970-01-01`.

Am I not understanding something, or is this a bug?

```java
package org.example;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class StreamingSparkPartitioned {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws TimeoutException, StreamingQueryException {
      SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
         .master("local[*]")
         .getOrCreate();

      Column expression =  when(expr("value % 3 = 1"), "stupid_event").otherwise(
         when(expr("value % 3 = 2"), "smart_event")
            .otherwise("neutral_event"));

      DataStreamWriter streamingDF = spark.readStream()
         .format("rate-micro-batch")
         .option("rowsPerBatch", "100")
         .option("startTimestamp", "10000")
         .load()
         .withColumn("event_type", expression)
         .writeStream()
         .option("checkpointLocation", "C:\\Users\\wnwnn\\Desktop\\checkpoint");

      streamingDF.outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
         .format("console")
         .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
         .start()
         .awaitTermination();
   }
}
```